# Pandas groupby with None

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

For a dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '1', None, None, '1', '2', '2', '3', None, '4'], 
               'last_name': ['Clinton', 'Clinton', 'Clinton','Clinton', None, 'Bush', 'Bush', None, 'Obama', 'Obama'],
               'first_name': ['Bill', 'William', 'Bill', 'William', None, 'Georg W.', 'Georg', None, 'Barack', 'Barack']})

df['id'] = df['id'].astype('category')
print(df)
```

which gives the following table

```
    id last_name first_name
0    1   Clinton       Bill
1    1   Clinton    William
2  NaN   Clinton       Bill
3  NaN   Clinton    William
4    1       NaN       None
5    2      Bush   Georg W.
6    2      Bush      Georg
7    3       NaN       None
8  NaN     Obama     Barack
9    4     Obama     Barack
```

I want to group by the `id` and `last_name`, drop duplicates, and remove `None` iff there is more than one entry. So the output should be like

```
              first_name
id  last_name           
1   Clinton       Bill
    Clinton       William
2   Bush          Georg W.
    Bush          Georg
3   None          None
4   Obama         Barack
```

One of my problems is that `groupby` does not work, because it excludes the `None` / `NaN` values.

Any elegant ideas?

Comment: I believe the thing is: drop `NaN`s only if group size is `>1`. But you cant group them all together in the first place, so don't think can do this. Is there any reason you have those NaNs? Maybe the problem is in building the data frame

Comment: Thanks @RafaelC that's exactly the problem.

Comment: Michael, I tried a solution. Assuming you have a "sorted" data frame, it should work. Take a look

Comment: I encountered this problem too, and decided to do `df["id"] = df["id"].fillna("None")` before my groupby operations. Groupby then takes the "None" into account, as it seems to be just a column value like all others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, assuming your data frame has the structure similar to the one you posted, you can use `ffill()` and group by it, and then `dropna` only if `len` of each group is greater than 1.

```
df.groupby([df.id.ffill(), df.last_name.ffill()]).apply(lambda s: s.dropna() if len(s) > 1 else s).reset_index(drop=True)

    id  last_name   first_name  id2
0   1   Clinton     Bill        1
1   1   Clinton     William     1
2   2   Bush        Georg W.    2
3   2   Bush        Georg       2
4   3   None        None        3
5   NaN Obama       Barack      3
```